# calculate sum total of nights

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have this code can some help me in this as it calculate total price by days but i need it calculated by nights ?

```
foreach($roomCalendar_info  as $roomCalendar_info_key   => $roomCalendar_info_arr)
{
    $room_price_sum += $this->view->price($roomCalendar_info_arr['room_price']) ;
    $room_item_details .= '<tr>';
    $room_item_details .= '<td style="line-height: 20px;">';
    $room_item_details .= $roomCalendar_info_arr['calendar_date'];
    $room_item_details .= '</td>';
    $room_item_details .= '<td style="line-height: 20px;">';
    $room_item_details .= $currencySymbol.' '.number_format($this->view->price($roomCalendar_info_arr['room_price']), 2, '.', ',').' '.$currencyShortName;
    $room_item_details .= '</td>';
    $room_item_details .= '</tr>';
}

$sub_total += $room_price_sum ;         
$cd++;
```

its solved now , thanks to the given answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want the last day's rate added to the total because it's checkout day.  In order to achieve this, you'll need to be able to detect when you are processing the last day inside your loop.  This should do the trick for you:

```
// Get the key of the last day
$roomCalendar_info_key_last_day = array_pop(array_keys($roomCalendar_info));

foreach($roomCalendar_info as $roomCalendar_info_key => $roomCalendar_info_arr)
{
    // Only add to the total if this is not the last day
    if ($roomCalendar_info_key != $roomCalendar_info_key_last_day)
        $room_price_sum += $this->view->price($roomCalendar_info_arr['room_price']) ;
    $room_item_details .= '<tr>';
    $room_item_details .= '<td style="line-height: 20px;">';
    $room_item_details .= $roomCalendar_info_arr['calendar_date'];
    $room_item_details .= '</td>';
    $room_item_details .= '<td style="line-height: 20px;">';
    $room_item_details .= $currencySymbol.' '.number_format($this->view->price($roomCalendar_info_arr['room_price']), 2, '.', ',').' '.$currencyShortName;
    $room_item_details .= '</td>';
    $room_item_details .= '</tr>';
}

$sub_total += $room_price_sum ;
$cd++;
```